# Create a link to a user ID in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a simple table and I want to navigate to the `user.id` but it throws off the formatting. Is there another way to do this or do I move LinkToUser?

I have removed all styling so there is nothing conflicting.

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export const LinkToUser = styled(Link)`
`

export const StyledTable = styled.table`
`;

export const THead = styled.thead`
`;

export const TR = styled.tr`
`;

export const TBody = styled.tbody`
`;

export const TH = styled.th`
`;

export const TD = styled.td`
`;
```

```
    <StyledTable>
        <THead>
            <TR>
                <TH>{copy.tableHeaderA}</TH>
                <TH>{copy.tableHeaderB}</TH>
                <TH>{copy.tableHeaderC}</TH>
            </TR>
        </THead>
        <TBody>
            {fetchedUsersData?.map((user: Users) => (
                <LinkToUser to={`/users/${user.id}`}>
                    <TR key={user.id}>
                        <TD>
                            <p>{user.username}</p>
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            <p>{user.name}</p>
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            <p>{user.company.name}</p>
                        </TD>
                    </TR>
                </LinkToUser>
            ))}
        </TBody>
    </StyledTable >
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use onClick and history if you are using react-router-dom

```js
<StyledTable>
        <THead>
            <TR>
                <TH>{copy.tableHeaderA}</TH>
                <TH>{copy.tableHeaderB}</TH>
                <TH>{copy.tableHeaderC}</TH>
            </TR>
        </THead>
        <TBody>
            {fetchedUsersData?.map((user: Users) => ( 
                    <TR key={user.id}
                     onClick={()=>{
                      history.push(`/users/${user.id}`)
                     }
                    >
                        <TD>
                            <p>{user.username}</p>
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            <p>{user.name}</p>
                        </TD>
                        <TD>
                            <p>{user.company.name}</p>
                        </TD>
                    </TR> 
            ))}
        </TBody>
    </StyledTable >
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move key to the parent component inside map function like this,
from:

```
{fetchedUsersData?.map((user: Users) => (
                <LinkToUser to={`/users/${user.id}`}>
                        <TR key={user.id}>
```

to:

```
{fetchedUsersData?.map((user: Users) => (
                <LinkToUser to={`/users/${user.id}`} key={user.id}>
                    <TR >
```

Also make sure this table is inside router parent tree.
Another problem might be to not be able to have Link as direct child of TableBody, in that case i suggest to move your link inside one of the TD elements

Comment: Thanks for your answer but moving the key did not solve it. LinkToUser works fine in TD but I want the whole row.

Comment: Maybe you can solve it with funtion call like this: <TR key={YourIndex} onClick={handleOnClick(user.id)}>

and function iside component: 
handleOnClick = (userid) => {
      return <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: "/profile",
        foo: userid
        
      }}
    />
    }

Comment: Thanks for your help. Went with react router :)